# Using text input as filter option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, user-input, angularjs-filter

I struggle with the usage of the filter. I have an input field that i want to use as a filter option.

The array looks like this:

```
 $scope.Examples=[
{
 name:'Dolly',
 place:'roof',
 description:'Dolly is a friend of Mike.'
},  
{ 
 name:'Mike',
 place:'cellar',
 decription:'Mike doesn't like the roof.'
},];

$scope.Search="";
```

The Input:

```
 <input ng-model="Search" 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="type something here">
```

And the ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="something in Examples |filter:Search">
{{something.name}}
</tr>
```

Now, if i type in "Dolly", he shows me *Dolly* quite as planned. But if i type in "Mike" the output is *Dolly* and *Mike*, because i used the word Mike in the description for Dolly. The same for typing in "roof".
I tried to use

```
<ng-repeat="something in Examples |filter:{name:'Search'}">
```

but in that case it simply don't work and there is no output. What i want to do is restrict the filter to 'name' only. Maybe someone have a suggestion how i could make it work.
I'm thankful for every advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write {name:'Search'} instead of {name:Search}, it means that you keep any string which contains the 'Search' string

Try this :

`<ng-repeat="something in Examples |filter:{name:Search}">`